# How to generate a random matrix with arbitrary correlation between elements?

Tags: matrix, random, correlation

I would like to find a smart way to generate a $N\times N$ random matrix $M$ with **arbitrary correlation**:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\langle M_{ij}M_{kl}\rangle=\tau_{ijkl}}
\end{equation}
Where the mean and variance of the elements are given by:
\begin{align}
\langle M_{ij}\rangle&=0 \\
\langle M_{ij}^2\rangle&=\sigma^2
\end{align}

---

The case I am interested in is actually a sub-problem of this. I would like to generate a matrix whose elements follow a normal distribution of mean $0$ and variance $1/N$, and whose elements are correlated the following way:
\begin{equation}
\langle M_{ij}M_{ki}\rangle=\tau_{ijk}
\end{equation}
When $\tau_{ijk}=\delta_{jk}N^{-1}$ I recover a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Use Cholesky factorisation

Answer (score 2):

Simplify $ij\to u$ and $kl\to v$: find $M_u$ such that $\langle M_u\rangle=0$ and $\langle M_u M_v\rangle=\tau_{u v}$. This notation makes the analysis a bit simpler.

We can achieve this effect by using the matrix-square-root of the matrix $T$ of elements $\tau_{u v}$. Example:

```
n = 3;
T = {{2, -1, 0.3}, {-1, 4, 1.3}, {0.3, 1.3, 2}};
SymmetricMatrixQ[T] && PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[T]
(*    True    *)
```

Using the matrix square root `MatrixPower[T, 1/2]` to generate $10^5$ lists of random numbers and computing their covariance matrix:

```
V = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^5, n}] . MatrixPower[T, 1/2];
Covariance[V]
(*    {{1.99821, -1.01062, 0.29987},
       {-1.01062, 4.03928, 1.28961},
       {0.29987, 1.28961, 1.99284}}    *)
```

We see that this covariance matrix matches the desired `T`.

Comment: How can I construct back my matrix $M$? It seems that for $n=3$ in your code my matrix $M$ does not exist. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: If at the end you want $4\times4$-matrices $M$ correlated by a $4\times4\times4\times4$-tensor of elements $\tau_{ijkl}$, then set $n=16$, flatten the correlation tensor out into a $16\times16$-matrix `T`, and generate random 16-vectors. Then, take each 16-vector and reshape it into a $4\times4$ matrix.